# How to check where I recently sent some Bitcoin Cash using Copay wallet

Tags: wallet, copay

Hey sorry but i'm totally new to this. i bought serval different currencies. i have sent bitcoin and bitcoin cash to my copay wallet. i can see the bitcoin but not the bitcoin cash. the balance has left my coinbase account. i don't understand enough to decipher what im looking at. i see input consumed and outputs created. and i see a load of confirmations. i copied and pasted the address from my wallet so i don't think i could have pasted them wrong. what are my next steps to take. ho do i check where i have send them.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the addresses your transactions went to?

Answer (score 1):

> **how do I check where I have sent them?**

View Recent Transactions.

[image: View wallet activity]

If they are not there, you may be able to [refresh the history from the Copay servers](https://github.com/bitpay/copay/issues/8657)

> - "Settings" > "Wallet" > "More Options" > "Transaction History" > "Clear cache"
> - "Settings" > "Wallet" > "More Options" > "Wallet Addresses" > "Scan addresses for funds"

You can paste the address or transaction ID into any BCH clockchain explorer ([example](https://explorer.bitcoin.com/bch)) to check another view of the transaction in a different copy of the blockchain ledger.